# Help with jTweetsAnywhere

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have started working with this plugin and need some help combining results... http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/

I need to have one thread of tweets showing on my page. The first is which displays my tweets...

```
$('#Tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
username: ['myname'],
count: 3
});
```

The second is to show any tweets that include @myname...

```
$('#Tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
searchParams: ['q=@shoes'],
count: 3
});
```

Obviously I can get these working as separate entities but I need to combine them.

Any ideas.

Many thanks,
c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#Tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
searchParams: ['q=shoes'],
count: 3
});
```

The search parameter is your name without the "@". Any tweets from you or containing a mention of you will display.

Answer (score 1):

Both ids (#Tweets) cannot be the same, it results in them trying to replace any div that say #tweets with whichever content overrides. Try this:

```
<div id="Tweets1"></div>
$('#Tweets1').jTweetsAnywhere({
username: ['myname'],
count: 3
});

<div id="Tweets2"></div>
$('#Tweets2').jTweetsAnywhere({
searchParams: ['q=@shoes'],
count: 3
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#Tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
    searchParams: ['q=%40shoes from:myname'],
    count: 3
});
```

You should use %40 instead of @.